# jquery :contains something OR something else

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the best way to implement the OR statement in a :contains jquery call?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is to put two of them [together](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector):

```
$('a:contains(b), a:contains(c)')
```